# iPhone - bluetooth on SDK 5.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, bluetooth

I make an app for iPhone with SDK 5.0.
This app can active bluetooth with one click but it doesn't work with SDK 5.1!
Have you an idea?

I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand that I want to do!

Comment: Please show us the code you have written to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I expect you are using the URL access schema for accessing the settings.

Apple removed this in iOS 5.1

Comment: @Adeline Reyz: True, if you were doing something like `NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth"]];` it's no longer available in 5.1

Comment: I know... but I search another method to do that on 5.1

Comment: You can't. They've not added one.

Comment: @AdelineReyz: Welcome to SO! You can (should) accept Nick's answer to mark this topic closed.